# Algorithm to obtain Cyclopean view from stereo images

Tags: stereo-3d

I'm doing a stereo vision program. I've found great algorithms to calculate the disparity map and implemented a couple. But I can't find any algorithms for obtaining the cyclopean view.

Been searching for hours and nothing found. I'm using the wrong technical term maybe?